# Ubuntu 14.04 privacy setting shows recent apps and files can be shown in dashboard and elsewhere. What here elsewhere means

Tags: settings, privacy

Ubuntu 14.04 privacy setting shows recent applications and files can be shown in dashboard and elsewhere. What here "elsewhere" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other programs on your computer can access and use this information, too, for example the "Activity Journal" (package `gnome-activity-journal`).

The data is not transferred to Canonical or anyone else but only stored locally on your computer.

Comment: "http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/is-zeitgeist-spying-on-you" found this one  very helpful.